# How to apply POS tag function to string in sentence from another column pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nltk

How to use POS tag for one word from another column using Pandas?

For example I have:

```
col1      col2
aaa1      AAa1 is a great friend
abb2      abb2 is a very good friend
```

I want to output:

```
NNP is a great friend
NN is a very good friend
```

I try:

```
from nltk import pos_tag
columns = ['col1', 'col2']
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter='\t', names=columns)
data["col2"] = data.apply(lambda x: x["col1"].replace(x["col1"], pos_tag([x["col2"], x["col1"]])[1][1]), axis=1)
```

But it doesn't working and don't ignore case letter.
My col1 is only in lowercase, In col2 i have lowercase and uppercase words. How to apply re sub module? 
I want to use it for each row (About 4 milions rows)

Edit: 
If I try use:

```
data["col2"] = data.apply(lambda x: re.sub(x["col1"], pos_tag([x["col1"].lower(), x["col1"].lower()]), x["col2"], flags=re.I), axis=1)
```

It doesn't working. Because I want output with original case letter. This is my target problem -> I want replace really string to NNP and NN for SVM classifier.

Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Would the `.lower()` method of Python's string class be enough solve this? If you think you need to use `re.sub`, perhaps you can give an example of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @rwp please check my edit

Answer (score 1):

A simple function can do this task. You can do like this:

```
## import libraries
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, pos_tag_sents

## tag the sentece
df['col2'] = df['col2'].apply(word_tokenize).apply(pos_tag)

## this function does the magic 
def get_vals(lst):
    op = [] 
    for i, v in enumerate(lst):
        if i == 0:
            op.append(v[1])
        else:
            op.append(v[0])
    return ' '.join(op)

## apply the function
df['col2'] = df['col2'].apply(get_vals)

print(df)

   col1                      col2
0  aaa1     NNP is a great friend
1  abb2  NN is a very good friend
```

**Updated Solution:**

This solution is suited to replace the string at any location with its POS tag.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['aaa1','abb2','mtmb2','mmm2','bb2'],
                   'col2':['AAa1 is a great friend','abb2 is a very good friend','MTMB2 is a my sentence','Your MmM2 is my sentence','Your sentence is bb2']})

## import libraries
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, pos_tag_sents

## tag the sentece
df['col2'] = df['col2'].str.lower().apply(word_tokenize).apply(pos_tag)
vals = df['col1'].tolist()

## this function does the magic 
def get_vals(lst):
    op = [] 
    for i, v in enumerate(lst):
        if v[0] in vals:
            op.append(v[1])
        else:
            op.append(v[0])

    return ' '.join(op)

## apply the function
df['col3'] = df['col2'].apply(get_vals)
```

Comment: It's not working. Its working only for word on 0 index position. How to write it for example, when I have sentence: 
Hello AAa1 is a very good friend -> Hello NNP is a very good friend

Comment: @belek in that case, do we know what all words we want to replace with the tags like AAa1 etc. If not, there needs to be a pattern on which I we can do this.

Comment: @belek I've added the updated solution. Let me know.